# Use Next.js with typescript but can not apply generic in WithRouterProps

Tags: typescript, router, next.js

I'm using VScode as IDE, giving generic to `withRouter` should be applied on props.router.query but not working

Have tried to create component interface and extends with withRouterProps, but props.router.query. still show nothing

```js
    import { withRouter, WithRouterProps } from 'next/router';
    import Layout from '../components/Layout';
    import React from 'react';

    class Page extends React.Component<IPageProps> {
        render() {
            console.log(this.props.router.query.);  <=== should show title in intellience but nothing happened 
            return (
                <Layout>
                    {/* <h1>{this.props}</h1> */}
                    <p>This is the blog post content.</p>
                </Layout>
            );
        }
    }

    export default withRouter(Page);

    interface IPageProps extends WithRouterProps<{ title: string }> {
        test: string;
    }
```

The generic should take place.
i.e. `withRouterProps<{ title: string }>` should make `props.router.query.title works`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom type:

```
type WithRouterPropsTyped<Query extends WithRouterProps["router"]["query"]> = WithRouterProps & {
  query: Query
}

const Component = (router: WithRouterPropsTyped<{title: string}>) => {
  return <div>Title: {router.query.title}</div>
}
```